# Script to perform slow movement with settimeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm writing a script to create slow movement in an element and it's not performing as I'd expect. I'm using `settimeout` to delay the action but right now it iterates past the limit of 5 `steps` and I'm not sure why. Thanks for taking a look!

```js
var step;
var steps = 5;

function init() {
 step = 0;
}

function render() {
  if (step < steps) {

    console.log("yo!");
    setTimeout(stepIncrease, 3000);
    console.log("steps:");
    console.log(steps);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function stepIncrease() {
    step++;
    console.log("step:");
    console.log(step);
}

init();
render();
```

Comment: You are misusing `requestAnimationFrame` with `setTimeout`. Basicly `requestAnimationFrame` is called 60 times in a second. So, before `stepIncrease` is executed (3 seconds later), the function `render` had executed `setTimeout` a lot of times

Comment: Have you think about to use `setInterval`?

Comment: @Amadeus, Ah, I think I understand. Is there a better approach to creating delays inside animation loops?

Comment: @kmgt, Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: Can't you just move `setTimeout(stepIncrease, 3000);` outside of your `render` function? (under `init(); render();`

Comment: You should move the if and the settimeout inside the stepIncrease function and call stepIncrease from init (to start the loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing requestAnimationFrame with setTimeout. Basicly requestAnimationFrame is called 60 times in a second. So, before stepIncrease is executed (3 seconds later), the function render had executed setTimeout several of times

Im not sure what you want to achieve, but the simplest solution is to move the `requestAnimationFrame` to be inside `stepIncrease()` function.

```js
var step;
var steps = 5;

function init() {
 step = 0;
}

function render() {
  if (step < steps) {

    console.log("yo!");
    setTimeout(stepIncrease, 3000);
    console.log("steps:");
    console.log(steps);
  }
}

function stepIncrease() {
    step++;
    console.log("step:");
    console.log(step);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

init();
render();
```

Answer (score 0):

`requestAnimationFrame()` means that you request the window to run the function before the next repaint of the window. `setTimeout()` will use a timeout in a different queue.

So since your render function contains `requestAnimationFrame(render);` you basically tell the computer: `do this function on every frame`. So you basically create an infinite loop here and the `setTimeout()`ed function will never run to increase the step counter.

```js
var step;
var steps = 5;

function init() {
 step = 0;
}

function render() {
  console.log("steps:");
  console.log(step);
  if (step < steps) {
    step++;
    console.log("yo!");
    setTimeout(render, 3000);
  }
}
init();
render();
```

Answer (score 0):

To delay the action **requestAnimationFrame** it's should be something like this

```
let step = 0;
let steps = 5;

const stepIncrease = () => {
    step++;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    console.log("step:", step);
}

function render() {
  if (step < steps) {

    console.log("yo!");
    setTimeout(stepIncrease, 3000);
    console.log("steps:", steps);
  }

}

render();
```

To understand what is actually happening, take a look this talk [What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)